# Rendering HTML template and sending context with it but fetch response is not reading context and showing error regarding JSON

Tags: javascript, django

I'm sending a context JSON object to template here in `views.py`. Everything else works properly.

### views.py

```py
def adminLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'admin/login.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and isAdmin(user.username):
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            context = {
                "login" : "Done",
                "token" : token.key,
                "username" : user.username,
                "email" : user.email,
            }
            print("admin login done")
            context = dumps(context)
            return render(request, 'admin/login.html', {"context" : context})
        else:
            print("login unseccesfull")
            return render(request, 'admin/not-login.html')
```

The context I'm catching in JavaScript and try to read context, but it failed to read that context. I'm even using `JOSN.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`, but neither are not working.

#### Template HTML

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var loginForm = document.getElementById("adminLogin");

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(this);
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  for (var pair of formData) {
    searchParams.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
  }

  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_admin/login/', {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: searchParams,
    })
    .then(res => {
      var context = JSON.stringify("{{context|escapejs")
      if (context.login === "Done") {
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem("username", context.username);
        localStorage.setItem("token", context.token);
        localStorage.setItem("email", context.email);
        localStorage.setItem("login", "done");
        window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_admin/";
      }

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
      alert("Something went wrong");
    });
})
</script>
```